# Convert string to date in databricks SQL

Tags: sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table with a text column in the following format:

```
5/30/2021 9:35:18 AM
```

I'm trying to convert this to `date(yyyy-MM-dd)` but I get null values when I use cast, `to_date`.
Is there any way to get the above data in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Databricks Datetime Patterns.** According to SparkSQL documentation on the Databricks website, you can use [datetime patterns](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) specific to Databricks to convert to and from date columns. First, you need to convert the text column to a date column like this:

```
to_date('5/30/2021 9:35:18 AM','M/d/y h:m:s a')
```

M - month, d - day of month, y - year, h - hour of day (12-hour), m - minute of hour, s - second of minute, a - AM/PM

Once the column is converted to a date, you can easily use the same datetime patterns to convert it back to a specific format. Use the following command to convert it to the required format:

```
date_format(to_date('5/30/2021 9:35:18 AM','M/d/y h:m:s a'), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

[removed extraneous word "date" in date_format() function]

Note: Depending upon whether you're getting zero left padded days, months, hours, minutes, and seconds, you'll need to tweak the above command.